# How to use linux memory map on iOS?

Tags: ios, linux, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

I want to read some big files on iOS device, to make iOS device a better memory, someone told me maybe I can use linux memory map on iOS, but I have no idea of it. Or there are some other ways on iOS platform just like linux memory map? Thx so much.

Comment: It would be better to avoid premature optimizations. Get your app working. Then, if there is a problem with large files, then look into iOS ways to work with larger files. Then, if you have an issue, post a more concrete question about your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, start with an instance of `NSData` and configure it to use memory mapping to map the contents of the file into memory.

As @rmaddy said, avoid premature optimizations.  Assuming that "big files" means "larger than physical memory", then start with the above.  If "big files" means "a few MB", then just read the files and be done with it until you quantify an actual performance issue.